# GitLab CE keeps resetting my external_url

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab

I'm running GitLab CE privately within an AWS VPC that I access via a VPN instance. I installed the latest AWS AMI of GitLab CE, then upgraded it to the latest version of GitLab. I've gotten everything working, except for one thing: Whenever I reboot the instance in EC2, my `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`'s `external_url` is reset to the IP address of my VPC's SNAT instance, almost as if GitLab is asking "what is my public IP?" and then changing the setting's value to that answer. I keep changing it back to the internal hostname provided by my VPC's Route 53 hosted zone, `https://gitlab.corp.mydomain.com`, but it's reset every time I reboot the instance. To be clear, this GitLab instance is *not* exposed to the internet, but it does have egress to the internet through the SNAT (e.g., to update OS packages).

How can I force my internal hostname to stick? I can still access GitLab through my browser at `https://gitlab.corp.mydomain.com`, so perhaps this doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick search I have found this.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/merge_requests/2021

Summary of the content:

It seems like Gitlabs hostname detection is not working correctly if public IPs are deactivated in EC2. To enable usage in such cases Gitlab replaces the hostname with the assigned IP. Gitlab will return to the hostname if it can resolve it later, at least from version 10.1.3.

As it works for you, I would simply keep the configuration.